# How to generate link of my profile in Android studio application

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have an application Where I have user profiles. what I want to do is generate their links when someone click share button and share with people so that people can visit their profile and subscribe. I am unable to understand how can I generate a link to a specific profile which shows specific data of a user.

```java
 String xyz = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

                dynamicLink = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
                        .setLink(Uri.parse("https://trian.page.link/" +xyz))
                        .setDomainUriPrefix("https://trian.page.link/")
                        .setAndroidParameters(new DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder().build())
                        .buildDynamicLink();
```

Also I am using this code to generate links but It is not registering to the firebase console.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share a link with other users that they can click to get to a specific screen in your app, have a look at [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links).

Comment: I added the following code. but it is not registering in the firebase console.